# Code sometimes creates duplicate rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, race-condition

I have the following code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE player_id = :player_id AND data_type = :data_type");

$sth->bindParam(':player_id', $player_id);
$sth->bindParam(':data_type', $total_time_data_type_id);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch();            

if(!$result){
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO stats (player_id, offset, created, modified, last_check, data_type, data) VALUES (:player_id, :offset, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '1', :total_time_data_type_id, '0')");

    $sth->bindParam(':player_id', $player_id);
    $sth->bindParam(':offset', $offset);
    $sth->bindParam(':total_time_data_type_id', $total_time_data_type_id);
    $sth->execute();

    if(!$sth){
        return false;
    }
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE player_id = :player_id AND data_type = :data_type");

    $sth->bindParam(':player_id', $player_id);
    $sth->bindParam(':data_type', $total_time_data_type_id);
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetch();
    if(!$result){
        return false;
    }
}else{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE stats SET .....");
    //Do more stuff
}
```

Now, occasionally this is creating duplicate rows (out of ~600 rows, there are 23 duplicates). This confuses me since before inserting the row I explicitly check for a row with the same `player_id` and `data_type`.

Multiple rows can exist for either the same `player_id` or `data_type`, but not the same of each.

I.E. This would be valid:

```
ID | PLAYER_ID | DATA_TYPE
---|-----------|----------
1  | 15        | 7
2  | 15        | 18
3  | 92        | 7
4  | 115       | 23
```

While this would not:

```
ID | PLAYER_ID | DATA_TYPE
---|-----------|----------
1  | 15        | 7        
2  | 32        | 18       
3  | 15        | 7        
4  | 115       | 23
```

Because of this I can't simply declare the `player_id` field as unique.

The only thing I can think of that may be causing this problem is the fact that the code snippet above is inside of a `foreach` loop averaging around 115 iterations, and that this code is called again within seconds. Is there a way to prevent this programmatically?

Comment: What happens when you have two copies of the code running at once? The first one can do its check and find it needs to add a player; if the second copy runs after that point but before the player has been added, you'll get duplicate entries.

Comment: @andrewsi That's what I assumed, but is there a way to prevent that programmatically?

Comment: Just use "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Comment: @DC_ - nikita2206's suggestion will do it at a database level. You can also use `flock()` to create a lockfile, and make sure that only one instance of your code can run at once.

Comment: @nikita2206 Though if you read my question, you'll see that the only invalid circumstance is when both `player_id` and `data_type` are the same, neither of which are keys.

Comment: You could use either table / file locks or transactions to combat race conditions like this.

Comment: @Jack Ah that's the term I was looking for. Will look into it, thanks.

Comment: player_id and data_type are not composite key? Why?

Comment: I mean - you don't need ID field here if you have two keys that can clearly determine row. You could just make PRIMARY KEY (player_id, data_type)

Comment: @nikita2206 Had no idea you could do that - very new to SQL, this is the first major project I've undertaken. Thanks for the suggestion, will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your help, especially @nikita2206. This is how I solved my problem:

1. Dropped column ID which was Primary Key.
2. Created new primary key on (Player_id, data_type).
3. Changed INSERT Statement:

From

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO stats (player_id, offset, created, modified, last_check, data_type, data) VALUES (:player_id, :offset, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '1', :total_time_data_type_id, '0')");
```

to

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO stats (player_id, offset, created, modified, last_check, data_type, data) VALUES (:player_id, :offset, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '1', :total_time_data_type_id, '0') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE player_id = player_id");
```

---

Tested by calling the code several times very quickly and no duplicates were created.